# Access variable from another movieclip

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

Hey i wanted to use a variable one two different MovieClips.

I have a MovieClip(mainGame) with this code

```
onClipEvent(load)
{
    var light:Boolean;
    light = true;
    trace("Game Loaded");

}

on(keyPress "x")
{
    if(light == false)
    {
        light = true;
        trace("light is on");
    }
    else if(light == true)
    {
        light = false;
        trace("light is off");
    }
}
```

This code toggles a boolean.

Now i have another MovieClip(enemy) in which i would like to access the boolean "light" and then make this MovieClip(enemy) visible or invisible depending on the boolean.

```
onClipEvent(enterFrame)
{
    if(light == true)
    {
        this._visible = false;
    }
    else if(light == false);
    {
        this._visible = true;
    }
}
```

thank you for the help,
Joao Silva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the `light` variable of your `mainGame` MovieClip from your `enemy` one, you can do :

```
_root.mainGame.light
```

So your code can be like this, for example :

```
// mainGame

onClipEvent(load)
{
    var light:Boolean = true;
    trace('Game Loaded');
}

on(keyPress 'x')
{
    // here we use the NOT (!) operator to inverse the value
    light = ! light;

    // here we use the conditional operator (?:)
    trace('light is ' + (light ? 'on' : 'off'));
}
```

and

```
// enemy

onClipEvent(enterFrame)
{   
     this._visible = ! _root.mainGame.light;
}
```

which you can also do from the `mainGame` MovieClip :

```
// mainGame

on(keyPress 'x')
{
    light = ! light;

    _root.enemy._visible = ! light;

    trace('light is ' + (light ? 'on' : 'off'));
}
```

For more about the [NOT (!) operator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000674.html), take a look [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000674.html), and about the [conditional operator (?:)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000631.html), from [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000631.html).

And as you are learning, you can start [learning ActionScript3](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning.html) [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning.html) ...

Hope that can help.